# Restore Terminal Tabs with Session History

Tags: terminal, time-machine, bash

I had a Terminal window with 7 or 8 tabs with a lot of history and long scrollback, with resume set to 10000 rows, that was always persisting between sessions. I have accidentally closed the window instead of quitting the Terminal app and I have lost this setup. I have a time machine backup from the day before. Is there a way to restore my tabs with their histories?

I have found these two possibly related Q&A, but I can’t figure out how to use that info to restore my tabs:

- [Restore specific Terminal history from .bash_sessions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311548/restore-specific-terminal-history-from-bash-sessions)
- [How do OS X terminal sessions persist through reboots?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278372/how-do-os-x-terminal-sessions-persist-through-reboots)

Answer (score 4):

The saved state of Terminal is stored in this folder.

```
~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/
```

Quit Terminal, copy the contents of this folder from your backup, then open Terminal.

Comment: :-( `Saved Application State` doesn’t appear to be part of Time Machine Backup… I guess that’s it then?

Comment: @Palimondo Oops, didn't think to [check that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GLXl.png); do you use APFS and have a snapshot you can roll back to?

Comment: Nope, just upgraded to High Sierra yesterday and I’m still on HFS+.

Comment: So, I have now saved a copy of `.bash_sessions` and `com.apple.Terminal.savedState` in hopes that something can be done to restore the tabs. But I cannot find any keys in the `windows.plist` that would match some IDs from sessions. The `data.data`, `window_1.data` and `window_2.data` seem inscrutable at first glance, but weighing at 143 KB, 5 KB and 204 KB respectably, I’m hoping they contain the scrollback rows. Any clues about their format?

Comment: Found this: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9426/how-to-read-nscr1000-data-files

Comment: So… I’m guessing the data files are encrypted and the keys were thrown away when I closed that window?! I have no further ideas…

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on these steps, seems easy, but not sure where to copy things to in order to restore? I'm using ZSH via terminal..